# Linq - Aggregate strings with quotes

Tags: c#, string, linq, aggregate-functions

I have the following problem:
When I use

```
 var newItems = {"one", "two"}
 var a = newItems.Aggregate((current, c) => current + ", \"" + c + "\"");
```

I get: "one, two"

Instead expected: "\"one\", \"two\""

Who can explain to me why it happens?

Comment: Actually your code returns `"one, \"two\""`... anyway, this is the right situation where you should use `string.Join("," , newItems.Select(x => "\"" + x +"\""))`

Comment: @digEmAll please post this as answer.

Comment: @digEmAll
Post your comment and I mark it as correct!

Comment: @AkashKava & OP: there are at least 2 valid answers, mine would be a duplicate, so please mark one of them ;)

Comment: You can also use Aggregate and StringBuilder to avoid any temporary strings although the code is a bit ugly. Or use String.Format and String.Join to avoid concatenations as much as possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do it this way

```
string output=String.Join(",",newItems.Select(x=>"\""+x+"\""));
```

---

Alternative solution

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
newItems.ToList()
        .ForEach(x=>sb.Append(","+String.Format("\"{0}\"",x)));
string output=sb.ToString().Trim(',');
```

Comment: @AkashKava That's a coincidence..Though he should have posted it as an answer

Comment: Coincidence with time difference of 4 minutes?

Comment: Well actually this answer is better than aggregates provided here. But can you add explanations why its better?

Comment: Using String.Join is such an **obvious** answer that a coincidence is far more believable than copying.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos actually..Though ans is valid cuz comment != answer..;)

Comment: Better use String.Format instead of string concatenation to avoid creating temporary strings. They can really hurt you when you process a lot of items frequently and the GC has no time to collect them

Comment: Calling `ToString` on a `List<string>` probably won't give anything useful.

Comment: "If you have a large number of elements you should use StringBuilder" -> not true, especially not with that code. `string.Join` internally is much more efficient than the code you write there, especially when there are a large number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Using aggregate with strings is not a very good idea, because it will create new string in memory on each iteration. I suggest you to use `String.Join` (internally uses `StringBuilder`) or directly use `StringBuilder` as accumulator:

```
var a = newItems.Aggregate(
          new StringBuilder(), // avoid intermediate strings creation
          (sb, s) => sb.AppendFormat("{0}\"{1}\"", sb.Length > 0 ? "," : "", s),
          sb => sb.ToString());
```

Thus you not just want to concatenate strings, but also Join them with some symbol, then `String.Join` is natural way of doing that.

Comment: A .Remove in the result selector to remove the trailing `,` makes this *slightly* less ugly. I'd still use String.Join/Format for more readable code unless performance really hurts. Or hide the entire construct in an extension method, hmmm ...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos agree, Remove looks better, and agree again I'd go with Join. +1 from me

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using string concatenation wherever possible. Strings are immutable so concatenating strings creates new temporary strings that have to be garbage collected later. This can be a serious issue if you perform many string operations regularly.

You can use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [String.Forma](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)t to create a delimited string from a list of values like this:

```
var newItems = new [] {"one", "two"};
var a = String.Join(", ",newItems.Select(c => String.Format("\"{0}\"",c)));
```

This does create temporary strings, although they are a lot fewer than before.

You can also use a StringBuilder and Aggregate to create a single string and avoid any temporary strings, although the code looks a bit ugly:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
var b1 = (newItems.Aggregate(builder,
            (bld, c) => bld.AppendFormat("\"{0}\",", c),
            bld => bld.Remove(bld.Length - 1, 1))
         ).ToString();
```

or even

```
 var b2 = newItems.Aggregate(builder2, 
         (bld, c) => bld.AppendFormat("\"{0}\",", c), 
         bld => bld.Remove(bld.Length - 1, 1).ToString());
```

If you need to use such code in many places, it would be better to hide the entire construct in an extension method:

```
public static string JoinFormat<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items,string format)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    var result = (items.Aggregate(builder,
            (bld, c) => bld.AppendFormat(format, c),
            bld => bld.Remove(bld.Length - 1, 1))
         ).ToString();
    return result;
}
```

and write:

```
var a=newItems.JoinFormat("\"{0}\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap both `current` and `c` around quotes:

```
var a = newItems.Aggregate((current, c) => "\"" + current + "\", \"" + c + "\"");
```

This code returns expected result.

Comment: For two inputs, yes, but it'll give too many quotes for three or more inputs.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that aggregate work with String.Empty as accumulate value, so ok and thanks, now I understand that I was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

By default, `Aggregate` will take its first value and use that as its seed, so it will take `one` and append `, "two"` to it. What you need to do is specify a blank seed and do something special when (i.e. not put the comma) you get a blank seed:

```
var newItems = new[] {"one", "two"};
var a = "The following items will be created: " + 
         newItems.Aggregate("", (current, c) =>
              (current == "" ? "" : current + ", ") + "\"" + c + "\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to embedd the previous and current element in quotes :

```
var newItems = new[]{"one", "two"};
var strout = '"' + newItems.Aggregate((a, b) =>  a +  "\", \"" + b)+ '"';
```

Result:

```
"one", "two"
```

Comment: For two inputs, yes, but it'll give too many quotes for three or more inputs.